# Get page content from client side (cross domain)

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Is there a way to get page content (cross domain) with just usage of JS (or some other scripting language) from client side without usage of server side script ?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a public page you can use **[YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)** and make it deliver jsonp results in a script tag, but other than that we are talking **[XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)** here, and that is a no-no.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the source of both pages, you can use [postMessage](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#introduction-9) in one page to send markup to the other.